# ¿Por qué no se crean las tablas y no se insertan los datos en mi base de datos de SQLite en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite

Estoy usando SQLite para almacenar los pedidos de mi app de comida a domicilio. Creo la base de datos con una clase DBHelper.java, y le digo que cree una tabla ORDERS. El problema esta en que no me crea la tabla ORDERS nunca y luego cuando llamo a un metodo para insertar datos en esta tabla, no inserta nada.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

final static String DBNAME = "mydatabase.db";
final static int DBVERSION = 1;

public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ORDERS " +
            "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "NAME TEXT," +
            "PHONE TEXT," +
            "PRICE TEXT," +
            "QUANTITY TEXT,"+
            "FOODNAME TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ORDERS");
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertOrder(String name, String phone, String price,String quantity, String foodname) {

    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", name);
    values.put("phone", phone);
    values.put("price", price);
    values.put("quantity", quantity);
    values.put("foodname", foodname);
    long id =         database.insert("orders", null, values);
    if(id <=0){
        return  false;

    }else return  true;

}
```

Tengo  el metodo onCreate en el cual me deberia crear la tabla ORDERS pero no la crea. Luego tengo un metodo que se llama insertOrder, el cual lo llamo en este onClickListener en otra clase:

```
 processorderbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            helper.insertOrder(MenuContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
                    "666666666",
                    MenuContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_PRICE,
                    MenuContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY,
                    MenuContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_NAME);


        }
    });
```

¿Por qué no me crea la tabla ORDERS nunca? ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Recuerda que si desarrollas en Android el uso del LogCat es indispensable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que el query para crear la tabla es correcto, pero posiblemente tienes una tabla con una estructura incorrecta, al querer insertar los datos marcaría error.

Te sugiero eliminar el caché o la aplicación y volver a instalarla, también puedes aumentar la versión de la base de datos:

```
final static int DBVERSION = 2;
```

esto para que se elimine la tabla, ya que llama a `onUpgrade()` y vuelva a llamar nuevamente el método que crea la estructura de la tabla:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ORDERS " +
            "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "NAME TEXT," +
            "PHONE TEXT," +
            "PRICE TEXT," +
            "QUANTITY TEXT,"+
            "FOODNAME TEXT)");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alguna vez me sucedió lo mismo, te recomendaría crear una variable estática en alguna clase para que pueda ser usada desde cualquier activity. Dentro de esa variable de tipo entero guarda la versión de la base de datos, si antes era la 0, cambiala a 1, si era 1 cambiala a 2, etc... de esa forma se actualizan tus nuevas tablas y hará lo que tienes en tu método onCreate.